# MIPS-I binary on MIPS32

Tags: linux, mips, mips32

I have a mipsel Linux system and would like to run a mipsel binary. However executing the binary results in

> ./m1: error while loading shared libraries: tl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ldd output looks very confusing:

```
tl => not found
nit => not found
itpid => not found
_file => not found
```

file output:

> m1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld.so.1, stripped

readelf output:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Ident Version:                     1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000 big-endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  Entry point address:               0x40b750
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1632496 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x1007
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program header entries:    32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers entries: 9
  Size of section header entries:    40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers entries: 29
  Section header string table index: 28

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name                 Type         Addr     Off    Size   ES Flags Lk Inf Al
[ 0] <corrupt>            SHT_LOPROC+3736f72 2d474e2d 2e332e31 34202933 1936683619 XMSINGTO 841888558 1128726528 673200707
[ 1] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 1196305772 2029332e 2e332e34 47000032 1311599727 WXSN  540689219 1869767464 1869902707
[ 2] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 691220019 0000322e 3a434347 72632820 858665774 ST    1953723247 762081135 825050958
[ 3] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 3288627 6328203a 73736f72 6c6f6f74 841888558 NGTO  759647789 775106097 874522931
[ 4] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 673200707 6f6f7473 474e2d6c 332e312d 540689219 WASIGO 539570990 775106100 1191182386
[ 5] <corrupt>            SHT_LOOS+f747373 2e312d47 29332e33 332e3420 1953723247 WAXSITO 12846 977486663 1919100960
[ 6] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 825050958 2e342029 322e33 43434700 759647789 AXSNG 1663574074 1936945010 1819242356
[ 7] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 874522931 43470000 28203a43 736f7263 539570990 AXSNG 1869575283 1196305772 858665261
[ 8] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 1191182386 6f726328 6f747373 4e2d6c6f 12846 WAING 774974791 691220019 858666016
[ 9] <corrupt>            SHT_LOPROC+2632820 2d6c6f6f 312d474e 332e332e 1663574074 WAXSINGO 775168041 3288627 1128482560
[10] <corrupt>            SHT_LOOS+c6f6f74 2e332e31 34202933 322e332e 1869575283 WXSGT 1128726528 673200707 1936683619
[11] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 858665261 2e332e34 47000032 203a4343 774974791 AXSNG 1869767464 1869902707 1311599727
[12] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 858666016 3a434347 72632820 7473736f 775168041 AXSG  762081135 825050958 858665774
[13] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 1128482560 73736f72 6c6f6f74 2d474e2d 1128726528 AMSO  775106097 874522931 841888558
[14] <corrupt>            SHT_LOPROC+36f7263 474e2d6c 332e312d 2029332e 1869767464 WAMSITO 775106100 1191182386 540689219
[15] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 1311599727 29332e33 332e3420 00322e 762081135 WAXINT 977486663 1919100960 1953723247
[16] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 858665774 00322e33 43434700 6328203a 775106097 WS    1936945010 1819242356 759647789
[17] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 841888558 28203a43 736f7263 6f6f7473 775106100 O     1196305772 858665261 539570990
[18] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 540689219 6f747373 4e2d6c6f 2e312d47 977486663 SNGO  691220019 858666016 12846
[19] <corrupt>            SHT_LOPROC+473736f 312d474e 332e332e 2e342029 1936945010 WAXSINGT 3288627 1128482560 1663574074
[20] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 759647789 34202933 322e332e 43470000 1196305772 WMSGT 673200707 1936683619 1869575283
[21] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 539570990 47000032 203a4343 6f726328 691220019 XMSGT 1869902707 1311599727 774974791
[22] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 12846 72632820 7473736f 2d6c6f6f 3288627 WAXING 825050958 858665774 775168041
[23] <corrupt>            SHT_LOOS+328203a 6c6f6f74 2d474e2d 2e332e31 673200707 AMSINGTO 874522931 841888558 1128726528
[24] <corrupt>            SHT_LOOS+f6f7473 332e312d 2029332e 2e332e34 1869902707 XSINTO 1191182386 540689219 1869767464
[25] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 774974791 332e3420 00322e 3a434347 825050958 WAMSGT 1919100960 1953723247 762081135
[26] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 775168041 43434700 6328203a 73736f72 874522931 WAMSGT 1819242356 759647789 775106097
[27] <corrupt>            <unknown>: 1128726528 736f7263 6f6f7473 474e2d6c 1191182386 WAIG  858665261 539570990 775106100
[28] <corrupt>            SHT_LOOS+f726328 4e2d6c6f 2e312d47 29332e33 1919100960 WAMSINGO 858666016 12846 977486663

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00400034 0x00400034 0x000120 0x000120 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000154 0x00400154 0x00400154 0x00000d 0x00000d R   0x1
    [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld.so.1]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00400000 0x00400000 0x18539c 0x18539c R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x18543c 0x0059543c 0x0059543c 0x007dd4 0x03fb64 RW  0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x000164 0x00400164 0x00400164 0x000120 0x000120 RWE 0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x185370 0x00585370 0x00585370 0x00002c 0x00002c R   0x4
  GNU_RELRO      0x18543c 0x0059543c 0x0059543c 0x004bc4 0x004bc4 R   0x1
  LOOS+84153728  0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000000 0x000000     0x4
  NULL           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000000 0x000000     0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     
   02     
   03     
   04     
   05     
   06     
   07     
   08
```

file output of a working binary on the same system:

> curl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld.so.1, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

uname -a:

> Linux 3.13.5 #1 SMP Sun Mar 5 19:11:59 CET 2017 mips GNU/Linux

Is there any possibility to get the binary running without recompiling it?

Comment: Hm, that `readelf` output is really, *really*, weird. That `big` is suspicious, though I'm not familiar enough with MIPS to know for sure.

Comment: Note also that there are a *lot* of systems whose interpreter is named `/lib/ld.so.1`, which are all incompatible with other, often in subtle ways ... but that wouldn't explain the `readelf` output.

Comment: Yeah... The binary runs without problems on a qemu emulated debian mipsel on my desktop computer.